# PHP how to properly loop through json with multiple levels as object

Tags: php, json, foreach

Here is the Json data stored in variable $json

```
[Data] => Array
        (    
    [id_number] => Array
            (
                [value] => 123445567
                [link] => <a href="some_link">1234556</a>
                [class] => 
            )

        [date] => Array
            (
                [value] => 04-18-14
                [link] => <a href="some_link">1234556</a>
                [class] => 
            )
```

Currently I access the lower levels like this:

```
foreach($json['Data'] as $data) {
  foreach ($data['id_number'] as $id) {
      print $id['value'];
  }
}
```

There is only one result for id_number and only one result for date. Do I really need this second foreach loop? Isn't there a way to access it by just going to the lower level as an object so it would be something like

`print $data->id_number->value`

Thank you.

Comment: `print $json['Data']['id_number']['value']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have decoded the JSON string as an array you could do

```
foreach($json['Data'] as $data) {
        print $data['id_number']['value'];
}
```

If you had decoded it into an object (don't set the second parameter to be `true`) then you could simply do it like you mentioned

```
foreach($json->Data as $data)
   print $data->id_number->value;
```

**[Manual](http://php.net/json_decode)**

Comment: Aha, perfect. Kudos for answering both of my questions. 1 - How to access it as an array and 2 - how to have it return as an object

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$json['Data'][idnr]->value
```

If you know the id that is ofc, else you will have to loop

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the elements individually (without looping) by:

```
$id_number = $json['Data']['id_number']['value'];
$date      = $json['Data']['date']['value'];
//etc ...
```